# get_template_part execute with ajax

Tags: ajax, get-template-part

I would like to get template part with AJAX. This template part - more-images.php contain of source some wp php and html.

I read AJAX is build in WP. So I put code below to my theme files.
My code:

functions.php

```
function get_img()
    {
    ob_start(); 
    get_template_part('more', 'images');
    die();
    ob_clean();
    }


add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_img', 'get_img' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_img', 'get_img' )
```

javascript file with other functions, loaded in the footer

```
    $.ajax({
            url: params.url,
            type: 'post',
             data: {  
                action: 'get_img',
success:  { $( 'main' ).append( data );         
     }, });
```

That code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need buffer here.

```
get_template_part('more', 'images');
die();
```

Comment: Thank You. However the code isn't working. I receive unexpected string. When I remove line: success:  { $( 'main' ).append( data );     it says params is not defined.